# Moving SKSpriteNode at constant speed with changing angle

Tags: ios, xcode, geometry, sprite-kit

Thanks in advance for any help anyone can give.

Being a beginning programer and having weak geometry skills, I find my self with the following problem.

I'm trying to have a "ship" steered by the user that moves around the screen at a content speed. Whatever direction the ship is pointing is the direction it moves (like in the game 15 Coins). The user can touch the right half of the screen to rotate the ship clockwise, or left to rotate the ship counter clockwise. If you hold down the ship continues to rotate.

The ship rotates correctly. However, the direction it moves is not what I'd expect. Each time I touch either on the right or left side of the screen (in the simulator) the ship will change the direction its moving between 45-180 degrees. I can't nail down a pattern to it. And I've spent a day with no success logging out values and trying to do the math on paper. Where am I going wrong?

Touches are handle through the following touchesBegan and touchesEned code and appear to happen correctly:

```
static const int dontRotate             = 0;
static const int rotateClockwise        = 1;
static const int rotateCounterClockwise = 2;


- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInNode:self.scene];

    if(touchLocation.x > screenWidth/2){
        shipRotation = rotateClockwise;
    }

    if(touchLocation.x <= screenWidth/2){
        shipRotation = rotateCounterClockwise;
    }
}


- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    shipRotation = dontRotate;
}
```

I'm updating the ship rotation, direction and location in update:

```
#define SK_DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(__ANGLE__) ((__ANGLE__) * 0.01745329252f)
#define SK_RADIANS_TO_DEGREES(__ANGLE__) ((__ANGLE__) * 57.29577951f)


-(void)update:(CFTimeInterval)currentTime {

        [self enumerateChildNodesWithName:@"player" usingBlock:^(SKNode *node, BOOL *stop) {

            shipOffsetAngle = shipDirection + SK_DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(90);
            shipLocation.x = shipLocation.x + speed * cos(SK_RADIANS_TO_DEGREES(shipOffsetAngle));
            shipLocation.y = shipLocation.y + speed * sin(SK_RADIANS_TO_DEGREES(shipOffsetAngle));

            node.position = shipLocation;

            if (shipRotation == rotateClockwise) {
                shipDirection = shipDirection - 0.01;
                node.zRotation = shipDirection;
            }

            if (shipRotation == rotateCounterClockwise) {
                shipDirection = shipDirection + 0.01;
                node.zRotation = shipDirection;
            }
        }];
}
```

As suggested by @LearnCocos2D I also tried the builtin GLKit conversion, but get the same results.

```
    test1 = SK_DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(90);
    test2 = 90 * (M_PI / 180);
    test3 = GLKMathDegreesToRadians(90);

    NSLog(@"test1 = %f", test1);
    NSLog(@"test2 = %f", test2);
    NSLog(@"test3 = %f", test3);
```

All log out as 1.570796

After a lot of fulling around I found my mistake. Below, In the first line shipoffsetAngle is in radians. In the next two sin/cos lines it tries to convert it to radians by multiplying it by 0.01745329252 using my SK_DEGREES_TO_RADIANS I had set up.

```
            shipOffsetAngle = shipDirection + SK_DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(90);
            shipLocation.x = shipLocation.x + speed * cos(SK_RADIANS_TO_DEGREES(shipOffsetAngle));
            shipLocation.y = shipLocation.y + speed * sin(SK_RADIANS_TO_DEGREES(shipOffsetAngle));
```

Below, I just took that out and switch to the GLKMathDegreesToRadians in GLKit and all is working now.

```
    shipOffsetAngle = shipDirection + GLKMathDegreesToRadians(90);
    shipLocation.x = shipLocation.x + speed * cos(shipOffsetAngle);
    shipLocation.y = shipLocation.y + speed * sin(shipOffsetAngle);
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. `sin()` and `cos()` expect radians, not degrees. Simple problem.

Comment: also there are builtin functions for deg/rad conversions https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GLkit/Reference/GLKMathUtils/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/GLKMathDegreesToRadians as well as existing defines: M_PI, M_PI_2, M_2_PI, etc. (see math.h)

Comment: @LearnCocos2D WoW. Thanks! there really is a wealth of stuff builtin. I'm only 2 weeks in, so i guess that'll come with time as I learn when/where to look. So thanks for that. But it looks like GLKMathDegreesToRadians is giving me the same results as my #define SK_DEGREES_TO_RADIANS. The code I used to check it is added above.

Comment: @duci9y That was one of my first of many mistakes. But I believe I am using radian measure.

Comment: Assuming you've fixed that mistake, did it sort out your problem? Or is there something else you're facing?

Comment: @duci9y My original code for covering to radians was correct (while not the built-in). So I'm still having the same issue with the ship seemingly heading off in random directions each time I touch and release. I'm going to hard code in a dozen or so various angles and see if that helps me get to the bottom of what's going on.

Comment: As I said, your code is incorrect. You need to pass radians to `sin()` not degrees. Are you doing that?

Comment: In the code I am using my #define SK_DEGREES_TO_RADIANS nested in my sin/cos operations to convert to radians. it multiplies the given degrees by 0.01745329252. The appears to be right?

Comment: @duci9y after hard coding the angles. I found the issue. shipOffsetAngle and shipDirection were already in radians. my code was then trying to convert then again by multiplying them by 0.01745329252. Which is why I got crazy results. I've added my updated working code I changed above. Thanks for your help.